# Hibernate, collections, save only certain properties

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to map following entities but i ran into some troubles with hibernate.

entities:

```
@Entity
public class MyObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;

    @Column(name = "anInt")
    int anInt;

    Set<MapValue> map = new hashset...

}

@Entity
public class MapValue {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id

    @Column(name="text")
    public String text;
    public double number; 
}
```

Value of the field "number" i want calculate after property "text" is set

Comment: You can either do this in a service layer or in the setter for `text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a "calculated" field, not persisted in the database, annotate it with `@Transient`.

```
@Transient
public double number;
```

Comment: What if i would like to calculate its value right after the field "text" is set?

imagine standart setter eg.:
    public void setText(string text) {
        this.text = text; 
        this.double = text.length/2;
    }

Comment: That would work also, but you would still need `@Transient` because all entity fields are by default persistent.